Conditional probability of being the better player at a game given that you win n matches.
Textbook Problem
I have a text book problem from the textbook Discrete Probability by Hugh Gordon; I'll copy it here (mostly verbatim).

No two members of the Piquet Club have the same skill at the game of piquet. In this game, chance and skill each play a role. Assume that, when two people play, the better player wins three-fourths of the time. Alice and Bob are two randomly chosen members of the club. What is the probability that Alice is the better player if:

Alice and Bob play one game, and Alice wins?
Alice and Bob play three games, and Alice wins just two of them?
Alice and Bob agree to decide a match on the basis of two out of three matches, and Alice wins the match?
Using a calculator where convenient, do parts 2 and 3 with "three" and "two" replaced by "nine" and "five" respectively.


(The problem Ch. 3.4 #68 if you happen to have the book, which is free online last I checked).
The problem itself seems pretty simple, but I'm stumped because I think there's just not enough information here. Or maybe I'm just missing something really obvious. I'll show my thought process so far, but I'll warn you in advance, I don't have much.
My Attempt
I think the givens translate into $P(\mathrm{Win_A |\,Better_A}) = 3/4$ where $\mathrm{Win_A}$ is the event that Alice wins a single match and $\mathrm{Better_A}$ is the event that Alice is the better player in her match.
And so in part 1. I think the problem is asking us to find what $P(\mathrm{Better_A |\,Win_A})$ is. I reached for Bayes' Theorem for this:
$$
\begin{align}
P(\mathrm{Better_A |\,Win_A}) &= \frac{P(\mathrm{Win_A |\,Better_A})P(\mathrm{Better_A})}{P(\mathrm{Win_A})} \\\\
& = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{P(\mathrm{Better_A})}{P(\mathrm{Win_A})}
\end{align}
$$
Although perhaps this was a mistake, since I don't think there's actually any way to find the new unknown probabilities.
I'm not even sure how to represent the givens from the other parts!

By symmetry, $P(Better_A)=P(Win_A)=\frac 12$ because when you select two random members you could get the better one first or second with equal probability and then the first one could win with probability $\frac 12$.  You have the answer to question $1$.
